# Conditional ng-options on select with Angular

Tags: angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a select that I'd like to change the ng-options display based upon the viewport. Here is a working example of using two selects, hiding/showing if mobile (using Bootstrap 3 classes). The styles of the select are conditional using CSS3, but I'd like to have the data be conditional as well.

```
<select id="selectSearchLocation"
    class="form-control search-location hidden-xs"
    ng-model="vm.searchLocation"
    ng-options="x.code as x.name +' (' + x.code + ')' for x in vm.searchLocations">
</select>
<select id="selectSearchLocation"
    class="form-control search-location visible-xs"
    ng-model="vm.searchLocation"
    ng-options="x.code as x.code for x in vm.searchLocations">
</select>
```

You can see the only difference is in the ng-options, the display/format "as" changes. i.e. "Colorado - CO" simply is "CO" for mobile if searchLocations is an array of State objects.

Could this be handled by a filter in Angular?

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple ways of doing this.  The first thing that comes to mind is to use a function instead of the literal value for the "as".

Something like:

```
ng-options="x.code as searchDisplay(x) for x in vm.searchLocations"
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.searchDisplay = function(searchLoc) {
  if (mobile) {
    return searchLoc.code;
  }
  return searchLoc.name + ' (' + searchLoc.code + ') ';
};
```